# 22.04 Prt Scr button not working

Tags: 22.04, screenshot, print-screen

I have Ubuntu 22.04. When I press the Prt Scr (Print Screen) to take a screenshot nothing happens. On another computer I have with 20.04 this works. Do I have to do something to enable this in 22.04?

Comment: Make sure you are holding the "Shift" key when pressing the PrtSc. On my keyboard you have to do that to make it work.

Comment: That worked! I suspect they changed the screenshot program between 20.04 and 22.04, because it didn't require shift before.

Comment: It looks like it uses "Spectacle" now. I think it used something called "gnome-screenshot" before.